# How to load files automatically via link/directory instead of manually with <input> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I wonder if there is a way to automatically load a Json file from a dircetory (lets say this: /Root/Data/datachart.json)

I have the following code parts.
But this way the user must select and upload the file.
But the file's name will always be the same and the path too. This chart is based on an automatically updated database table import. I need the file to automacally load by the given path and filename.

```
<div>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <input type="file" id="file-selector" multiple/>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1200px; height: 500px"></div>
    </body>
</div>


Script:

const fileSelector = document.getElementById('file-selector');
            fileSelector.addEventListener('change', function(event){
                const fileList = event.target.files;
                readFile(fileList[0]);
```

Unfortunetly so far i didn't found any solution on the web. So thank you the help for advance!

Comment: For the security reasons, no, there's no way JS could access the local system of a visitor without their interaction. Maybe you could use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead of the file ..?

Comment: There isnt any workaround in the whole planet? :)

Comment: If there was, it would be a huge security hole, just think about arbitrary web pages crawling around in your own machine. You can provide a browser extension to your users, it can limitedly read files directly.

Comment: I understand, thank you by the way. :)